# REST URLs mapping and physical implementation in PHP

Tags: php, api, rest, url

I am starting my first REST-based application and have a probably trivial question.

Example: a resource "Book":

1- GET www.domain.com/api/book/     - gets all the Books (possible parameters in body)
2- GET www.domain.com/api/book/1234 - gets the detailes of the Book instance with the ID=1234 (no params in body)
3- GET GET www.domain.com/api/book/1234/author - gets the Author of the book with the ID=1234

I am wondering about the physical server side implementation of these services. In which PHP files will the corresponding code be stored? Is there some server configuration to be done?

I guess I will have a server folder structure similar to this one:
 api/book/
 api/author/

...and some php files inside:
 api/book/file.php
 api/author/file.php

Should I also have a physical folder  api/book/1234 or it is somehow asumed to be handled by the script in api/book/?

Thankys and regards!

Where should I code the implementation of the

Comment: do you use some framework?

Comment: @pregmatch: yet to be defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In general**

1. You should redirect all of your requests to one file with htaccess+mod_rewite.
2. Then you should parse URI with PHP.
3. A Controller class to decide what action to execute basing on parsed parameters.

For example:

```
www.domain.com/api/book/1234
```

You parse it to:

```
action: book
id:     1234
```

So you run `showBook()` action with parameter `1234` - `showBook(1234)`, which will do all the rest of work.

**But...**

I recommend to use some simple framework for REST applications. For example [Slim Framework](http://www.slimframework.com/).

Comment: Good answer. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller - also will be useful for author of question.

Comment: @dragoste: By "all of your requests to one file" you mean "all app requests" or all "book-related requests"?
In other words, should I have only one entry-PHP file app-wide or somehow finer grained structure?

Comment: I meant all requests across whole your application. This is the most popular way to do such things. But if you think, it would be better for you to do it other way, that's fine. It's not the only solution.

Comment: Generally it would be good idea to get a little into MVC (mentioned by OZ_) to understand some basic ideas of designing application's architectures.